# Can I use JupyerLab in the remote server?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, jupyter-notebook

I have been used Jupyter notebook on the remote server (Ubuntu 14.04).
I tried JupyterLab on the local server (mac OS) and it is very useful.
How can I use JupyterLab on the remote server? I have searched many pages, but I could not find the information.

Comment: I have solved this question.
On remote server, I run `jupyter lab`, then I got `The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:10001/` message.